# Clipping geometries in PostGIS table if they are inside polygon?

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, kml, clip

I have polygons defined in KML files just like [this one](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/iowa.kml), which I can easily parse. Example:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
-91.463940,40.372660,0
-91.483790,40.379440,0
-91.493780,40.392410,0
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

I would like to run queries on a postgis table and clip all lines that intersect this polygon. Segments of the lines within the polygon should be deleted. Something like this:

```
    ____
___|poly|___line
___|    |___line
   |____|
```

Here's the table structure:

```
    Column    |     Type
--------------+---------------
 ogc_fid      | integer
 wkb_geometry | geometry 
 id           | numeric(8,0)  
 ele          | numeric(12,3)
```

Is this possible?

What would a query look like?

I assume I need to express the polygon in WKT format and use the documented ST_Intersects method, but I'm not sure how to put this together and modify the geometries.

Can this be done with PyQGIS?

I've loaded my kml file as a QgsVectorLayer, I can access the polygon feature and I can check if it intersects a rectangle:

```
l = QgsVectorLayer(sys.argv[1], "REGION", "ogr")
r = QgsRectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
for feature in l.getFeatures():
    if (feature.geometry().intersects(r)):
        return True
```

Comment: What do you mean by clear but not deleted? That sounds like a question about style rather than geometry?

Comment: Rephrased the question for clarity. This is not about style, this is about clipping and deleting geometries in the table.

Comment: Does HeyOverThere's answer not do what you are looking for?

Comment: Please decide whether you are looking for an SQL or PyQGIS answer to your question. I suggest editing it to be SQL so as not to strand the current answer and then asking a new question about PyQGIS.

Answer (score 5):

You need [ST_Difference](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) which returns the the geometry of a feature that does not intersect with another feature.  In your case something like this:

```
SELECT l.id, ST_Difference(l.geom, p.wkb_geometry) As diff_geom
FROM
lines l, polygons p
```

Modify for your actual table and field names.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. That SELECT would give me tens of gigs of data though, inserting that into a new table and then dropping the original table is not an option. I guess I need the exact **opposite** of ST_Difference, so I could do a DELETE.

Also: how exactly can I use my set of points as the polygon in the query you suggested?

Comment: You are likely to have problems if you are short of space  (something you should have said in the original post). You can't do a direct delete, as you are splitting lines (where they intersect polygons) and creating new smaller lines, so this is essentially a delete plus an insert operation. You could do it as an update, if you were prepared for each split LineString to become a MultiLinestring. However, whether it is a delete + insert, or an update, you are still likely to need a fair bit of space, as Postgres needs to save the previous state, in case the transaction needs to be rolled back.

Comment: @JohnBarça I see. I will try to find space. MultiLinestrings are fine. How would an update query look? Also, **how can I create the polygon in the query from my set of points?** Thanks.

Comment: Here's the PostgreSQL doc for `UPDATE` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html.
You could also first run a `DELETE` on the table to remove any lines completely contained by a polygon